# How to declare function prototype that returns std iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, polymorphism

So as a class assignment I'm reimplementing `std::vector`, and I'm having trouble with declaring the prototype for:

```
iterator insert ( iterator position, const T& x );
```

The template for my iterator class looks like this

```
template<typename T>
class VectorIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T>
```

The template for my vector class looks like this

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
```

How can I declare the prototype for insert to return `std::iterator` instead of my own `VectorIterator` class?  I will of course be returning an instance of my own VectorIterator class.

Comment: You should use the `random_access_iterator_tag` for a `vector` class, not the `input_iterator_tag`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function doesn't return a `std::iterator`; it returns a `std::vector<T, Alloc>::iterator`.  You need to typedef your `VectorIterator` in your `Vector`:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
    typedef VectorIterator<T> iterator;
};
```

This is the return type of the `insert` function.  Any references to `iterator` and `const_iterator` in the `std::vector` specification are to the typedefs that you need to provide.